# wp_verify_nonce() is showing me false value every time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a login form which I validate using WordPress Ajax call. When the user press the submit button they got this error because of the email is not activated:

```
echo json_encode(
    array(
        'loggedin'      =>  false, 
        'message'       =>  __("Your email not activated! please <b><a href='#' id='resend_email'>click</a></b> here to active your email", 'listeo_core'),
        'resend_nonce'   => wp_create_nonce('resend_nonce')
    )    
);
die();
```

So above code is showing me this output:

> Your email not activated! please click here to active your email

So, I have written a another ajax call when the user clicks on **here** link:

**here is the jQuery code:**

```
$(".notification").on("click", "#resend_email", function (e) { // <-- see second argument of .on
    e.preventDefault();                            
    var user_login = $("#user_login").val();
    var resend_nonce = data.resend_nonce;
                              
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: listeo_login.ajaxurl,
        data: { 
            action: 'resend_action',
            _wpnonce_resend: resend_nonce,
            user_login : user_login
           },
     
        }).done( function( data ) {
            console.log( data );   
        }       
    })
});
```

**Now for this request, I am using the following PHP code**

```
// Resend email     
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_resend_action', array( $this, 'resend_email' ) );

function resend_email () {   
    
    var_dump( wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST['_wpnonce_resend'], 'resend_nonce' ) );        
    echo json_encode([
        'okay' => 'I am fine'
    ]);    
    die();      
}
```

Now why, this **var_dump** is showing **false** value? Is there any reasones?

Comment: Have you tried checking that $_REQUEST['_wpnonce_resend'] actually contains the nonce? since looking at the source code of wp_verify_nonce it early quits if it is empty

Comment: Yes, I got this value : `Array
(
    [action] => resend_action
    [_wpnonce_resend] => f0f9d89a67
    [user_login] => kanta
    [woocommerce-login-nonce] => 
    [_wpnonce] => 
    [woocommerce-reset-password-nonce] => 
)`